# Karma doesn't run test after converting to requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner

To prefix the problem currently the test runs, but it seems to hang, it launches the browser but doesn't exit the browser on its own and appears to not be running the code in the test. I'm thinking it's not running because the final test file isn't being loaded by the browser, but I'm not sure why. Here's my `karma.conf.js`

```
// Generated on Mon Nov 18 2013 01:47:10 GMT-0600 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: 'app/scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/scripts/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/spec/**/*.js', included: false},
      'test/test-main.js',
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

`test/test-main.js`

```
'use strict';
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if ( window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file) ) {
            if (/spec\.js$/i.test(file)) {
                    tests.push(file);
            }
    }
}

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/src',
    paths: {
            'jQuery'          :'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery',
            'angular'         :'app/bower_components/angular/angular',
            'angular-sanitize':'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
            'angular-route'   :'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
            'angular-mocks'   :'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks'
    },
    shim: {
            'jQuery'          : { 'exports':'jQuery'},
            'angular'         : { 'exports':'angular', 'deps':['jQuery'] },
            'angular-sanitize': ['angular'],
            'angular-route'   : ['angular']
    },
    deps: tests,
},[
    'domReady',
    'controllers/main',
], function(domReady) {
    domReady(function() {
            console.log('testing');
            window.__karma__.start;
    })
});
```

`test/spec/controllers/main.js`

```
define(['angular','angular-mocks','controllers/insert'], function( angular, mocks, app ) {
    'use strict';

    describe('Controller: Insert', function () {
            // load the controller's module
            beforeEach(module('pasteyApp'));

            var Insert,
            scope;

            // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
            beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
                    scope = $rootScope.$new();
                    Insert = $controller('Insert', {
                      $scope: scope
                    });
            }));

            it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
                    expect(scope.code).toBeDefined;
            });
    });

});
```

`grunt test` output

```
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining ).
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.4 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [launcher]: Creating temp dir at /tmp/karma-26802229
DEBUG [launcher]: chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/karma-26802229 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --start-maximized http://localhost:9876/?id=26802229
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/app.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/controllers.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/controllers/insert.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/controllers/render.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/main.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/pastey.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/routes.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/app/scripts/services.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/test/spec/controllers/insert.js
    /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/test/test-main.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket nNwHTFhgWd4VWMXxdmm0
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux)]: Connected on socket nNwHTFhgWd4VWMXxdmm0
DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/test/test-main.js
DEBUG [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux)]: Disconnected during run, waiting for reconnecting.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exitted with code 0
ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.

DEBUG [launcher]: Cleaning temp dir /tmp/karma-26802229
WARN [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux)]: Disconnected
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (4.751 secs / 0 secs)
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
DEBUG [launcher]: Killing Chrome
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Elapsed time
concurrent:test  2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 25%
karma:unit       6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 74%
Total 8s
```

Comment: here's [all the code](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/pastey-frontend/src/18395be9f42ee65927143e05717bb83bce4c83d8/) if needed, I can add relevant files to here.

Comment: I also use requirejs with angular. I found convenient to load angular and angular-mocks directly by karma but not by requirejs. Anyway almost all tests will need to use inject and module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the really big thing here was that `karma.conf.js` wasn't loading all of the bower files. Then some of the `test-main.js` paths were wrong.

```
files: [
    'test/test-main.js',
    {pattern: 'test/spec/**/*.js',            included: false},
    {pattern: 'app/scripts/**/*.js',          included: false},
    {pattern: 'app/scripts/*.js',             included: false},
    {pattern: 'app/bower_components/**/*.js', included: false},
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
    '**/*.swp',
    'app/bower_components/**/*min.js',
    'app/scripts/main.js',
],
```

I have not gotten the created loop array to work

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (/spec\.js$/i.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
            console.log( file );
    }
}

require.config({
baseUrl: '/base/app/scripts',
    paths: {
            'domReady'        :'../bower_components/requirejs-domready/domReady',
            'jquery'          :'../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
            'angular'         :'../bower_components/angular/angular',
            'angular-sanitize':'../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
            'angular-route'   :'../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
            'angular-mocks'   :'../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
            'crypto'          :'../bower_components/cryptojs/lib/Crypto',
            'crypto.MD5'      :'../bower_components/cryptojs/lib/MD5',
            'highlight'       :'../bower_components/highlightjs/highlight.pack',
    },
    shim: {
            'jquery'          : { 'exports':'jquery'},
            'angular'         : { 'exports':'angular', 'deps':['jquery'] },
            'angular-sanitize': [ 'angular' ],
            'angular-route'   : [ 'angular' ],
            'angular-mocks'   : [ 'angular' ],
            'crypto.MD5'      : [ 'crypto'  ],
    },
deps: ['pastey','/base/test/spec/controllers/insert.js'],
    callback: window.__karma__.start,
});
```

Comment: A few quick questions, if you please: What is baseUrl: `'/base'`? -- does karma need to have "/base" -- what should I set base to? Do I need to add all of my dependencies (paths, shim, etc) into `test-main.js` (even though I have them in `root/main.js`, my app's require.config file)? What does `{pattern: ...',included: bool}` do (in a nutshell)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change order of rules in files array. It looks like first rule have higher priority:

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'test/test-main.js',    included: true},
    {pattern: 'test/spec/**/*.js',    included: false},
    ...
],
```

`tests/test-main.js` should be loaded into browser to bootstrap requirejs application. Other modules will be loaded by requirejs.